# I'm creating a puppeteer script that logs into ICloud and stores the session to generate alias, but getting redirect to homepage after successful 2FA

Tags: node.js, cookies, puppeteer, icloud

I'm trying to create an automated generation script that creates IClouds, but I'm getting redirected back to the homepage after successfully inputting the 2FA code. From what it seems, it's redirecting me back to the homepage because I'm getting the error "421 Misdirected Request" within the POST endpoint - https://setup.icloud.com/setup/ws/1/validate. After checking, puppeteer is failing to collect the X-APPLE-WEBAUTH-TOKEN cookie. I've tried countless things, but the only way to collect the cookie is after inputting the 2FA code, I tried scraping it before hand, but it returns empty. If anyone has any ideas to a solution, I'm all ears. The login process is manual, meaning once puppeteer clicks on the selector "ui-button[class="push primary sign-in-button"]", the user has to take over to complete the sign in process.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const inquirer = require('inquirer');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const { createCursor } = require('ghost-cursor');
const { Webhook, MessageBuilder } = require('discord-webhook-node');


const settings = require('../../../User Data/settings.json');
const { launchBrowsers } = require('../../../Functions/launchBrowsers');
const createColorizedLogger = require('../../../Functions/logger');
const logger = createColorizedLogger();

const USERAGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36';
const SECHUA = 'Google Chrome";v="113", "Chromium";v="113", "Not-A.Brand";v="24';

(async () => {
    const tasksInput = await inquirer.prompt([
      {
        type: 'number',
        name: 'count',
        message: 'How many tasks do you want to run?',
        default: 1,
      },
      {
        type: 'number',
        name: 'totalAccounts',
        message: 'How many accounts do you want to generate?',
        default: 1,
      },
      {
        type: 'confirm',
        name: 'useProxy',
        message: 'Do you want to use a proxy? (If no, localhost will be used)',
        default: true,
      },
    ]);
  
    let allPages = [];
    let allBrowsers = [];
  
    const totalTasks = tasksInput.count;
    const totalAccounts = tasksInput.totalAccounts;
  
  const { browsers, pages } = await launchBrowsers(totalTasks, tasksInput.useProxy);
  allBrowsers = browsers;
  allPages = pages;
  
  
for (let accountIndex = 0; accountIndex < totalAccounts; accountIndex++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < allPages.length; i++) {
        const page = allPages[i];
        const cursor = createCursor(page);
        await page.setRequestInterception(true);


    page.on('request', async (request) => {
      if (request.url().startsWith('https://setup.icloud.com/setup/ws/1/accountLogin')) {
        const headers = {
          'Accept': '*/*',
          'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
          'Connection': 'keep-alive',
          'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
          'Origin': 'https://www.icloud.com',
          'Referer': 'https://www.icloud.com/',
          'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
          'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
          'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site',
          'Sec-GPC': '1',
          'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
          'dnt': '1',
          'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="113", "Chromium";v="113", "Not-A.Brand";v="24"',
          'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
          'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"'
        };
          request.continue({ headers });

      } else {
          request.continue();
            }
        });
    
try {
    await page.goto('https://www.icloud.com/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 15000 });
} catch (error) {
        logger.error("Failed To Load Login Page, Retrying...");
      await page.reload();
    }

    await cursor.click('ui-button[class="push primary sign-in-button"]');
      logger.warn("Complete Sign-In...");

    const xpathAfterSignIn = '/html/body/div[1]/ui-main-pane/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/main/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]';

    await page.waitForXPath(xpathAfterSignIn, { visible: true, timeout: 500000 });
    logger.info("Sign-in Successful...");

  try {
      const cookies = await page.cookies();
      const cookiesObj = cookies.reduce((accum, cookie) => {
          accum[cookie.name] = cookie.value;
          return accum;
      }, {});
  
      const bodyHTML = await page.content();
      const $ = cheerio.load(bodyHTML);
  
      const clientBuildNumber = await page.$eval('html', (element) => element.getAttribute('data-cw-private-build-number'));
      const number = await page.$eval('html', (element) => element.getAttribute('data-cw-private-mastering-number'));
  
      const theId = uuidv4();
  
      const headers = {
          'Accept': '*/*',
          'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
          'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
          'Connection': 'keep-alive',
          'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
          'Origin': 'https://www.icloud.com',
          'Pragma': 'no-cache',
          'Referer': 'https://www.icloud.com/',
          'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
          'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
          'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site',
          'User-Agent': USERAGENT,
          'sec-ch-ua': SECHUA,
          'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
          'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
      };
  
      const params = {
          clientBuildNumber: clientBuildNumber,
          clientMasteringNumber: number,
          clientId: theId,
      };
  
      const postData = 'null';
  
      const responsePOST = await axios.post('https://setup.icloud.com/setup/ws/1/validate', params, { headers, cookies: cookiesObj, data: postData });
  
      const jsonData = JSON.parse(responsePOST.data);
  
      const dsid = jsonData.dsInfo.dsid;
      const notificationId = jsonData.dsInfo.notificationId;
      const aDsID = jsonData.dsInfo.aDsID;
      const primaryEmail = jsonData.dsInfo.primaryEmail;
      const pNumber = jsonData.webservices.reminders.url.split("//")[1].split("-")[0];
      
      logger.info("Client Build Number: ", clientBuildNumber);
      logger.info("Number: ", number);
      logger.info("DSID: ", dsid);
      logger.info("Notification ID: ", notificationId);
      logger.info("aDsID: ", aDsID);
      logger.info("Primary Email: ", primaryEmail);
      logger.info("PNumber: ", pNumber);
  
  } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
  } 
}};

for (const browser of allBrowsers) {
    await browser.close();
  };
})();
```